# Why doesn't Invalidate() method work for my custom button in design time?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, custom-controls, invalidation

I am working on my custom button in WinForm. I am already done at the work. But I have one last problem that my button doesn't `Invalidate` the area when a property was changed. I call the `Invalidate` method in  `set` block and `OnResize`, but it doesn't work for the button. But it is fixed at runtime or rebuild. How can I fix it?

Here is the a picture for example:

[image]

My code:

```
    public class AltoButton : Control
            {
                int radius;
                RoundedRectangle roundedRect;
                Color inactive1, inactive2, pressed1, pressed2;
                LinearGradientBrush InactiveGB, MouseOverGB, BorderGB, currentGB;
                public AltoButton()
                {
                    inactive1 = Color.FromArgb(44, 188, 210);
                    inactive2 = Color.FromArgb(33, 167, 188);

                    pressed1 = Color.FromArgb(64, 168, 183);
                    pressed2 = Color.FromArgb(36, 164, 183);

                    radius = 10;
                    roundedRect = new RoundedRectangle(Width, Height, radius);

                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
                             ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                }

                protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
                {
                    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    roundedRect = new RoundedRectangle(Width, Height, radius);
                    InactiveGB = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), inactive1, inactive2, 90f);
                    MouseOverGB = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), pressed1, pressed2, 90f);
                    BorderGB = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), Color.FromArgb(162, 120, 101), Color.FromArgb(162, 120, 101), 90f);
                    if (currentGB == null)
                        currentGB = InactiveGB;
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(currentGB, roundedRect.Path);
                    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(BorderGB), roundedRect.Path);
                }
                protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
                {
                    Invalidate();
                    base.OnResize(e);
                }
                protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
                {
                    currentGB = MouseOverGB;
                    Invalidate();
                    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
                }
                protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
                {
                    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
                    currentGB = InactiveGB;
                    Invalidate();
                }
                public int Radius
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return radius;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        radius = value;
                        Invalidate();
                    }
                }
    }
    public class RoundedRectangle
        {
            Point location;
            int radius;
            GraphicsPath grPath;
            public RoundedRectangle(int width, int height, int radius)
            {
                location = new Point(0, 0);
                this.radius = radius;

                Rectangle upperLeftRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
                Rectangle upperRightRect = new Rectangle(width - 2 * radius - 1, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
                Rectangle lowerLeftRect = new Rectangle(0, height - 2 * radius - 1, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
                Rectangle lowerRightRect = new Rectangle(width - 2 * radius - 1, height - 2 * radius - 1, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

                grPath = new GraphicsPath();
                grPath.AddArc(upperLeftRect, 180, 90);
                grPath.AddArc(upperRightRect, 270, 90);
                grPath.AddArc(lowerRightRect, 0, 90);
                grPath.AddArc(lowerLeftRect, 90, 90);
                grPath.CloseAllFigures();

            }
            public RoundedRectangle()
            {
            }
            public GraphicsPath Path
            {
                get
                {
                    return grPath;
                }
            }
            public Rectangle Rect
            {
                get
                {
                    return new Rectangle(location.X, location.Y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
                }
            }
        }
 public int Radius
        {
            get
            {
                return radius;
            }
            set
            {
                radius = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        public Color Inactive1
        {
            get
            {
                return inactive1;
            }
            set
            {
                inactive1 = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        public Color Inactive2
        {
            get
            {
                return inactive2;
            }
            set
            {
                inactive2 = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        public Color Pressed1
        {
            get
            {
                return pressed1;
            }
            set
            {
                pressed1 = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        public Color Pressed2
        {
            get
            {
                return pressed2;
            }
            set
            {
                pressed2 = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `currentGB` field is bugged.  It refers to the old brush, not the new one you created that has the correct size.  Just don't store brushes, they are very cheap to create but very expensive to keep around.  You'll now also have a shot at using the *using* statement correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `OnResize` override and include `ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw` in the styles that you set to `true`.

Or alternatively set [Control.ResizeRedraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`.

**UPDATE:** Actually the problem is more trivial. You have a cached brush in `currentGB` field which is created using a specific `Width` and `Height`.

So you can keep your code the way it is, and just set `currentGB` to `null` (you should really be disposing all these brushes, but that's another story) when the size is changed:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    currentGB = null;
    Invalidate();
    base.OnResize(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, it worked great. Actually, I am storing the brushes for browsable properties (get-set) such as colors. If the brushes are disposed after using, how can I get the current designer property value? The remaining code that I didnt add before is in updated question above. Maybe there is more efficient way. Take a look at that please.

Comment: Ok, I did what you say. Nothing stored. Just used mouse state and if-else conditions. Thanks again @Ivan.You are great.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan said above, I have used `using` statement to dispose after used. I have added this answer as a complementary solution.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            roundedRect = new RoundedRectangle(Width, Height, radius);

            if (state == MouseState.Leave)
                using (LinearGradientBrush inactiveGB = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), inactive1, inactive2, 90f))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(inactiveGB, roundedRect.Path);
            else if (state == MouseState.Over)
                using (LinearGradientBrush activeGB = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), active1, active2, 90f))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(activeGB, roundedRect.Path);

            using (LinearGradientBrush BorderGB = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), Color.FromArgb(162, 120, 101), Color.FromArgb(162, 120, 101), 90f))
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(BorderGB), roundedRect.Path);
        }
        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
            base.OnResize(e);
        }
        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            state = MouseState.Over;
            Invalidate();
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        }
```